# Need ETL graph example to extract data from Webtrends

Tags: rest, url, generator, gooddata, webtrends

Isn't there any ETL graph sample project or reference using REST connector to extract Webtrends report data by REST URL generated by version 3 generator?

Comment: Seek for tutorial / sample project in Google please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Webtrends tutorial](http://help.webtrends.com/en/dxapi/api_description.html) and corresponding GoodData REST Connector setup. Feel free to ask if you have any exact questions or problems with implementation.